# Jmeter functional test validation with sql and csv file

Tags: csv, jmeter

Currently I am trying to use Jmeter for functional tests, but I am currently stuck on how to best implement flexible test validation.

The ultimate goal would be to have a csv file for data input and validation, so it is easy for other people to add or remove test cases.

Case:

1. Login
2. Execute bulk job (involving a variable nr of objects and creating a variable nr of objects)
3. Validate the result via datase sql statements. (multiple SQL requests and response assertions)
4. Logout

Some statements I would like to execute:

- Nr of invoiced BI (per contract ID)
- Nr of distinct invoice ID's for BI with invoice ID (per contract ID)

*Get list of Invoice ID's to use in following SQL statement:

- For list of invoice ID's invoice header must be equal to....
- For list of invoice ID's invoice lines must be equal to....

For each sql I would use a response assertion to validate the sql result. Response assertion with for example 10 lines with a variable inside each line and OR statement to match/equal at least one of the lines.
Data is generated, so ID's can be different each run, I am only sure that the data for an object should match one of x cases.

Everything is very dynamic and the nr of check varies for each test case that is being executed from the csv file.
So I imagine I would need a foreach controller for each sql statement/check/assertion

CSV file would look something like this:

- Bulk Job / Contracts / Contract Validation / Invoice header validation /
- 1234 / 12345 / 2 / 456
- 1234 / 12435 / 5 / 968
- 4256 / 89754 / 1 / 987465
- 4256 / 78597 / 4 / 654
- 4256 / 87596 / 2 / 852

Or like this:

- Bulk Job / Contracts / Contract Validation / Invoice header validation /
- 1234 , 12345:12435 , 2:5 , 456:968
- 4256 , 89754:78597:87596 , 1:4:2 , 987465:654:852

What would be the best way to store and setup something like this? CSV file or xml or ...?
Maybe use multiple csv files and try to keep everything aligned?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using scripting-based option i.e. [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

If you provide `Result variable name` in the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler:

[image]

You will be able to get the Result Set as a single object:

[image]

Which is basically an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

[image]

So you will be able to iterate it in a single simple function

[image]

So you should be able to perform dynamic assertions in one shot.

Check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more information if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you are suggesting that I store the test data + validation in a database and add them to variables this way, instead of using a csv or xml file?

Comment: This approach might help you to reduce the number of loops/assertions and make your test more readable and easy to support